# visual studios 2010 atl web service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service, atl

Can anyone tell me where to find an visual studios 2010 atl web service template like the one that comes with visual studios 2008?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [comments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments) on the Visual C++ Team Blog they were removed starting with Visual Studio 2008. However, you can find the latest version on [codeplex](http://atlserver.codeplex.com/). There may be a way to use the latest compiler to build such a project, by utilizing the project template from the a previous version of Visual Studio. This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2008/01/17/building-with-atlserver-based-soap-project-with-visual-studio-2008.aspx) provides a description of how it could be done.